# Send notification before and after every CronJob run in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

Please help me to know how can I send a notification before and after every CronJob run in kubernetes. I explored defining before and after job but they don't run everytime when CronJob trigger as per its schedule.